# How to change button colors upon click (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two buttons. When one is clicked, I want it to turn from gray to black and stay black unless the page is refreshed *or* the other button is clicked. If the other button is clicked, I would like it to turn black and for the first one to go back to gray. I assume JS is the best way for this, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is some of my code below:

HTML:

```
 <a id="button"></a>
 <a id="button"></a>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
display:inline-block;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't assign the same id to multiple elements. This is what classes are for.

Comment: An id must be unique on your page

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any effort here. SO is not a code writing service. Besides, this type of functionality has been covered millions of times before.

Comment: It's not possible to do with CSS only. You need to use javascript/jQuery

Comment: @RuhulAmin I added a solution below with only CSS using the `:checked` state of radio buttons.

Comment: The OP asked for `button`, not `radio`.  See my answer for how to do it with actual `buttons`

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup The OP's example uses `<a>` tags that are named `button` - he does not ask for `button` elements.

Comment: @JonUleis Are we talking about form elements here? I don't think so.

Comment: @RuhulAmin We actually have no context for how the OP intends to use these buttons, but the behavior he's requesting is identical to that of native radio buttons.

Comment: Guys, I made a JavaScript free solution with anchors :p. And by the way, remember we're here to help, not fight. Now let's find some real questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID names should not be reused, change them to a class name instead, but they will still need an unique ID name each for us to apply Javascript logic to them.

html:

```
<a id="button1" class="button"></a>
<a id="button2" class="button"></a>
```

css:

```
.button 
            {
                display:inline-block;
                height:10px;
                width:10px;
                border-radius:10px;
            }
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor ="gray";
document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundColor ="gray";


document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){
            this.style.backgroundColor ="black";
            document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundColor ="gray";
        };

document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function(){
            this.style.backgroundColor ="black";
            document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor ="gray";
        };
```

Comment: Only answer to actually work, thank you. One issue I have now and would appreciate you helping me resolve it, is the fact that when I hover over a button after either one has been clicked, there is no longer a change of color when hovered over. Also in my script I had: .button:hover {background-color:black;}. This works before a button is clicked, but as soon as either button is clicked, there is no longer a hover effect over either button.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I whipped up with no JavaScript - instead I'm using two radio buttons that are styled depending on which one is "checked".

http://codepen.io/capitalq/pen/gLWLMK

```css
.button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  background: gray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button:checked {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="button" name="buttons" id="button1" />
<input type="radio" class="button" name="buttons" id="button2" />
```

Comment: Nice idea, until you actually need the buttons to work. At which point you will need `js` either for the button action or for storing the active state. I'll think of a way to do both without `js`, as I like your challenge. +1 for thinking outsude the box, though.

Comment: Check it out. Keep on thinking out of the box. Chapeau.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery addClass function to add a class with a set background.
The class will remain until there is a page load.

CSS Only aproach is :active, but it will not work on buttons, because the active property fades away once you release the click button. Maybe using an  tag disguised as button may work, but will fade away once it losses the active state.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do it quite easily.

```js
$('#buttons .item').on("click",function(){
    $("#buttons .item.active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
button{
  color: white;
}
.item{
  background-color: gray;
}
.active{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="item">Button 1</button>
  <button class="item">Button 2</button>
  <button class="item">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style media="screen">
    #buttonA, #buttonB {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: gray;
    }
</style>

<a id="buttonA"></a>
<a id="buttonB"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var buttonA = document.querySelector('#buttonA');
    var buttonB = document.querySelector('#buttonB');

    var changeColour = function (e) {

        if (e.target === buttonA) {
            buttonA.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            buttonB.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        }

        if (e.target === buttonB) {
            buttonB.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            buttonA.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        }

    };

    buttonA.addEventListener('click', changeColour, false);
    buttonB.addEventListener('click', changeColour, false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an HTML `button` element. So if you want to mark up a button on your page, you really ought to use:

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

Here is an approach using `<button>` and `classList` in javascript:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

function paintItBlack() {

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.remove('clicked');
    }

    this.classList.add('clicked');
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click',paintItBlack,false);
}
```

```css
.clicked {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Button A</button>
<button type="button">Button B</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is unnecessary at this time. Use this code in your .css file or in the "style" tag on the html file.. It will be black when the mouse is over it and after you click.

```
   a:hover
   {
       background-color:black;
   }
   a:target 
   {
       background-color:black;
   }
```

Comment: I want this to apply only to 'button', not all links. I have tried that, and it doesn't work. No effect at all.